# performance loop while get data from gridFS

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, gridfs

I'm using `pymongo` to get the data from gridFS, the loop while getting this data is really slow.

Is it possible to avoid that loop, or is any way to do that faster??

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from pprint import pprint
import bson
from gridfs import GridFS
import json
import pandas as pd

client = MongoClient()

client.database_names()
db = client['MC']

fs = GridFS(db, collection="MC")

db.collection_names(include_system_collections=False)
collectionFiles = db['MC.files']
collectionChunk = db['MC.chunks']

files = db['MC.files'].find({"metadata.Feature0": "00011"})

for n in files:
    file_id = n['_id']
    chunks = db['MotorCalculo.chunks'].find({"files_id": file_id})
    bsondData = (fs.get(file_id).read())
    decData = bsondData.decode()
    jsonData = json.loads(decData)
    F1 = jsonData['Feature1']
    F2 = jsonData['Feature2']
```

Comment: that loop is the only way??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have enough RAM, it should be faster to access file groups and not make as many calls to mongo.

You can try something like this:

```
batch_file_id = ['#1', '#2', '#3', '#4']
chunks = db['MotorCalculo.chunks'].find('{\"files_id\" : {\"$in\":[{\"$oid\":\"' + '\"}, {\"$oid\":\"'.join(batch_file_id) + '\"}]}}')
```

...

```
batch_file_id
Out[1]: ['#1', '#2', '#3', '#4']

'{\"files_id\" : {\"$in\":[{\"$oid\":\"' + '\"}, {\"$oid\":\"'.join(batch_file_id) + '\"}]}}'
Out[2]: '{"files_id" : {"$in":[{"$oid":"#1"}, {"$oid":"#2"}, {"$oid":"#3"}, {"$oid":"#4"}]}}'
```

Regards!!